# How to pass parameters which are stored in class

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, asp.net-web-api

I am using WebApi and have defined method which accept parameters stored in class

```
 public class MyParameters
    {
        [DataMember(IsRequired = true, Name = "Name")]
        public string Name{ get; set; }

        [DataMember(IsRequired = true, Name = "Age")]
        public string Age{ get; set; }


    }
```

My method is as below

```
public HttpResponseMessage GiveMeNames(MyParameters getParameters)
    {

        //My logic

    }
```

Now i want to pass this parameters through javascript file and i am using XMLHttpRequest

```
 var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("POST", "./api/GiveMeNames");
        xhr.responseType = "arrayBuffer";
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/zip");

        xhr.onload = function () {
            if (this.status === 200) {
                var blob = new Blob([this.response], { type: "application/zip" });

                window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, "SaveFile.zip");
            }
        };
        xhr.send();
```

How can i pass paramters to this request?

Comment: Anyone has answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I created object in javascript like below

```
var myRequest =
         {
             Name: "Test", Age: "33"
         };
```

Then in request i stringify and send it in XMLHttpRequest

```
xhr.send(JSON.stringify(myRequest));
```